# How can I call a jQuery function when an image changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a page with images and text.

A user can upload an image through a modal window. I use .js.erb to replace the image on the page with the one the user uploaded.

```
$('#mailing_body').contents().find("[data-edit-img='<%=escape_javascript(@user_image.location)%>']").attr('src', '<%=escape_javascript(@user_image.image.url(:medium))%>');
```

Now I want to a jquery function to fire when the image on the page changes.

I tried the following in my js file:

```
  $("#mailing_body").contents().find("[data-edit-img='header']").live('change',function(){
      alert('change');
  });
```

But it does not work.  What am I doing wrong?

I am using Ruby 1.9, Rails 3.2.2 jquery1.7.2

Comment: Wouldnt it be easyer to use a callback function, that runs after the upload has finished?

Comment: What @ChristianRomeni suggest is more appropriate. If you can execute callback functions then you might want to add an event trigger. For example `$(document).trigger('changedImage');` `$(document).bind('changedImage', function(){ do my action here. })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQueries `Change` only works on `INPUT` elements, unfortunately.

What you will have to to is create an event handler and fire a trigger.
When ever the upload is finished or whenever you expect the image to change you can use [jQueries event and trigger system](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```
$('#foo').bind('customEvent', function() {
      alert($(this).text());
});

$('#foo').trigger('customEvent');
```

Answer (score 0):

Change is a an event that get trigger on input element only when their value as change. It doesn't get triggered if an attribute get changed. What you want is something that watch for attribute changes. Here is a link that explains how to achieve such things, basically it's just using a timeout to check periodically that the attribute has changed.

http://darcyclarke.me/development/detect-attribute-changes-with-jquery/

In IE you can use propertychange which will get triggered on those changes but that's IE only.